# best way to find maximum age element of List

Tags: java, math

```
List<Man> list=new ArrayList<Man>();

Man manA = new Man(29);  // constructor parameter is age, use manA.age to get 29
list.add(manA);
Man manB = new Man(23);
list.add(manB);
Man manC = new Man(42);
list.add(manC);
Man manD = new Man(38);
list.add(manD);
```

I want get the maximum age element `manC` in `list`,

What's the best(fastest) way to do this?

Comment: Do you have to use a list? Why not use one of the ordered collections? When exactly is speed important to you? Adding them? Or querying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No matter what, you're going to have to do it in O(N) time unless you use something other than a list.

```
Man maxAge = new Man(0);
for(Man man : list) {
  if(man.age > maxAge.age) {
    maxAge = man;
  }
}
```

This will simply go through the entire list, recording the man with the greatest age it has encountered yet. When the loop is finished, maxAge will be the oldest of them all.

**Edit:**

In response to your comment about Collections.max being "better", I thought I'd just include this note just so no one is confused. It is better in the sense that interfacing a comparator is good practice and the fact that it is part of java.util is nice too. However, if you look at the source code (attached below) it does exactly the same thing. So algorithmically, it is not better (faster, as you mentioned above).

```
public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max(
  Collection<? extends T> collection) {
  Iterator<? extends T> it = collection.iterator();
  T max = it.next();
  while (it.hasNext()) {
    T next = it.next();
    if (max.compareTo(next) < 0) {
      max = next;
    }
  }
  return max;
}
```

Comment: I find a method `Collections.max(Collection coll, Comparator comp)`，I think this is better

Comment: @Zenofo, your method will require you to provide a Comparator. You could also use Collections.Max(Collection coll) but you'll have to implement Comparable. If you're going to find the max, min or sort a collection of Man multiple times, it's advisable to implement Comparable so you can make use of Collections to do them for you.

Comment: @Zenofo You asked for the fastest, not the most readable. They're the same worst case, though.

Comment: Using Collections.max is probably better stylistically, but is still going to take O(N) time. There is no getting around the fact that in order to identify the oldest Man, you must consider the age of every Man.

Comment: And what if `list` is empty, then `maxAge` will point to the bogus `new Man(0)`.

Answer (score 3):

Or you could add the Man objects to **TreeSet** which uses Red-Black tree underlying. That means the tree maintains the order when adding. It's O(log(N)).

Comment: +1. If retrieving max/min will be used often, I also recommend using ordered collections (eg. TreeSet)

Comment: The best solution would be a max-heap, no? O(1)

Comment: Use a TreeSet, and then for the cost of writing a simple Comparator, you can then call last() for highest age, first() for lowest age, and other potentially useful methods.

Answer (score 2):

```
Man maxAge = null;
for (Man man: list)
{
    if (maxAge==null || man.getAge() > maxAge.getAge())
        maxAge = man;
}
```