# java determine max element of the list of objects

Tags: java, arraylist, max

I have an `ArrayList` of objects and I need to find the maximum. The case is practically the same as here ([best way to find maximum age element of List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425184/best-way-to-find-maximum-age-element-of-list)). Ian Bishop answer suits well, but when n objects have the same age, then I need to say that there is no maximum and print `"Equals" + maxAge`.

How this code can be modified to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using an extra `boolean` to check:

```
Man maxAge = new Man(0);
boolean isAmaxFoud = false;

for(Man man : list) {
  if(man.age > maxAge.age) {
    maxAge = man;
    isAmaxFound = true;
  }
}

if(!isAmaxFound) // <<--- all age are equal
      print "Equals "+list.get(0)
else print maxAge
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to get the max value once, iterate through the list and keep track of the maximum so far. If you also keep a `boolean` to tell if you've seen the max value more than once, and set it to false when you find a new maximum and true when you find a value equal to your maximum, then that should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple modification of the accepted answer:

```
Man maxAge = null;
boolean unique = true;
for(Man man : list) {
    if (maxAge == null) {
        maxAge = man;
        unique = true;
    } else if (man.age > maxAge.age) {
        maxAge = man;
        unique = true;
    } else if (man.age == maxAge.age) {
        unique = false;
    }
}
if (maxAge == null) {
    System.out.println("Empty list!");
} else {
    if (unique) {
        System.out.println("Max age: " + maxAge.age);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Max age is not unique; equals " + maxAge.age);
    }
}
```